# Simoultanious data insertion into a list with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm trying to optimize a small program. So here is the basic idea:

I have an array of unfiltered data, and I wanna pass that to a function which will call another function, twice, for data filtering and insertion to a new list. The first call will take the data from original array in range from 0 => half of arrays length, and the second will do the same, but with range from half, to the last item. This way, I should make simultaneous insertion of filtered data into the same list. After the insertion is completed the filtered list can be passed to the rest of the program. Here's the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] 
        {
            // the unfiltered list
            int[] oldArray = new int[6] {1,2,3,4,5,6};
            // filtered list
            List<int> newList= new List<int>();
            // Functions is my static class
            Functions.Insert(newList, oldArray )
            Continue_Program_With_Filtered_List(newList);
            // remaining functions...
        }
```

And here is the Function class:

```
public static class Functions
{
    public static void Insert(List<int> newList, int[] oldArray)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Inserter(newList, oldArray, true);
        }).Start();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Inserter(newList, oldArray, false);
        }).Start();

        // I need to wait the result here of both threads
        // and make sure that every item from oldArray has been filtered
        // before I proceed to the next function in Main()
    }

    public static void Inserter(List<int> newList, int[] oldArray, bool countUp)
    {
        bool filterIsValid = false;
        int length = oldArray.Length;
        int halflen = (int)Math.Floor((decimal)length / 2);
        if (countUp)
        {
            // from half length to 0
            for (int i = 0; i < halflen; i++)
            {
                // filtering conditions here to set value of filterIsValid
                if(filterIsValid)
                    newList.Add(oldArray[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // from half length to full length
            for (int i = halflen + 1; i < length; i++)
            {
                // filtering conditions here to set value of filterIsValid
                if(filterIsValid)
                    newList.Add(oldArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is that I must await Function.Insert() to complete every thread, and pass through every item *before* the newList is passed to the next function in Main().

I've no idea how to use Tasks or async method on something like this. This is just an outline of the program by the way. Any help?

Comment: .NET already has concurrent collections, eg ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentDictionary. If you want to make `List` thread-safe you *have* to use `lock` when trying to read/write to it. You *can't* ensure thread-safety with condition checks. `List`'s modification methods aren't thread-safe

Comment: Another option would be to return a list from each thread and merge these lists when the threads have finished their work. So you have not to care about concurrent writes, but that expects that the item order is in the order needed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 
What you say is true. Even with this tiny mock data, the insertion is already dodgy. Didn't knew about ConcurrentQueue namespace. Thx

Comment: @user743414
Forgot to mention, order does not matter. This list will be inserted into the dictionary, and then searched when needed. Optionally, I'll use the answer above, and try inserting it into Concurrent Dictionary right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case using [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq) may also an option.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // the unfiltered list
    int[] oldArray = new int[6] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    // filtered list
    List<int> newList = oldArray.AsParallel().Where(filter).ToList();
    // remaining functions...
}
```

You can also use [`AsOrdered()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered?view=netframework-4.7.2) to preserve order

---

To come back to your initial question, here's what you can do
**Note:** Solution with minimal changes to your original code, whether there are other possible optimizations or not
**Additional Note:** Keep in mind that there can still be concurrency issues depending on what else you do with the arguments passing to that function.

```
public static async Task Insert(List<int> newList, int[] oldArray)
{
    ConcurrentBag<int> concurrentBag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Inserter(concurrentBag, oldArray, true);
    });
    var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Inserter(concurrentBag, oldArray, false);
    });
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    newList.AddRange(concurrentBag);
}

public static void Inserter(ConcurrentBag<int> newList, int[] oldArray, bool countUp)
{
    //Same code
}
```

**Edit:** Your second `for-loop` is wrong, change it to this or you will loose one item

```
for (int i = halflen; i < length; i++)
```

Comment: Yes, there are some concurrency issues. But at least I'm on the right track now.Combining these answers should do the trick. I'll post when I test this a little bit more. There's  lots of new information that I've got from these responses.